# TypeScript - How to define model in combination with using mongoose populate?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

### Background

I'm using mongoose and TypeScript in my Node.JS app. I'm using mongoose's `populate` in a bunch of places when fetching data from the database.

The issue I'm facing is that I don't know how to type my models so that a property can be either an ObjectId or populated with data from another collection.

### What I've tried

I've attempted using union types in my model type definition, which seems like something that TypeScript offers to cover these kind of things:

```
interface User extends Document {
    _id: Types.ObjectId;
    name: string
}

interface Item extends Document {
    _id: Types.ObjectId;

    // Union typing here
    user: Types.ObjectId | User;
}
```

My schema only defines the property as an ObjectId with ref.

```
const ItemSchema = new Schema({
    user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User", index: true }
})
```

**Example**:

So I might do something like this:

```
ItemModel.findById(id).populate("user").then((item: Item) => {
    console.log(item.user.name);
})
```

Which produces the compilation error:

```
[ts] Property 'name' does not exist on type 'User | ObjectId'.
     Property 'name' does not exist on type 'ObjectId'.
```

### Question

How can I have a model property that can be either of two types in TypeScript?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to use a type guard to narrow the type from `Types.ObjectId | User` to `User`...

If you are dealing with a `User` class, you can use this:

```
if (item.user instanceof User) {
    console.log(item.user.name);
} else {
    // Otherwise, it is a Types.ObjectId
}
```

If you have a structure that matches a `User`, but not an instance of a class (for example if `User` is an interface), you'll need a custom type guard:

```
function isUser(obj: User | any) : obj is User {
    return (obj && obj.name && typeof obj.name === 'string');
}
```

Which you can use with:

```
if (isUser(item.user)) {
    console.log(item.user.name);
} else {
    // Otherwise, it is a Types.ObjectId
}
```

If you don't want to check structures for this purpose, you could use a [discriminated union](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/_/ZEtADwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA23).

Comment: I did read about type guards and tried to apply them, but my tsc outputs error for them. It says `[ts] 'User' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.` for the row `if (item.user instanceof User) { ... }`

Comment: @maxpaj `instanceof` needs a concrete type - it won't work with interfaces. The second option with the custom type guard is needed for that.

Comment: That worked very well for me and gave me the clue to read into type guards in general. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry but it's not working. As said by maxpaj, you have an error 'User' only refers to a type.... and with typeof obj === 'Interface' it will always returns false

Answer (score 4):

Cast the `item.user` to `User`, when the user is populated.

```js
ItemModel.findById(id).populate("user").then((item: Item) => {
    console.log((<User>item.user).name);
})
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `PopulatedDoc` type from the `@types/mongoose` lib. See [mongoose.doc](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/typescript/populate.html).

Comment: It returns `any` as type, not a desired behavior

Comment: "we recommend using the .populate<{ child: Child }> syntax from the first section instead of PopulatedDoc".
The docs you linked do provide a better answer than the accepted one, though.

Answer (score 2):

Mongoose's TypeScript bindings export a PopulatedDoc type that helps you define populated documents in your TypeScript definitions:

```
import { Schema, model, Document, PopulatedDoc } from 'mongoose';

// `child` is either an ObjectId or a populated document
interface Parent {
  child?: PopulatedDoc<Child & Document>,
  name?: string
}
const ParentModel = model<Parent>('Parent', new Schema({
  child: { type: 'ObjectId', ref: 'Child' },
  name: String
}));

interface Child {
  name?: string;
}
const childSchema: Schema = new Schema({ name: String });
const ChildModel = model<Child>('Child', childSchema);

ParentModel.findOne({}).populate('child').orFail().then((doc: Parent) => {
  // Works
  doc.child.name.trim();
})
```

Below is a simplified implementation of the PopulatedDoc type. It takes 2 generic parameters: the populated document type PopulatedType, and the unpopulated type RawId. RawId defaults to an ObjectId.

```
type PopulatedDoc<PopulatedType, RawId = Types.ObjectId> = PopulatedType | RawId;
```

You as the developer are responsible for enforcing strong typing between populated and non-populated docs. Below is an example.

```
ParentModel.findOne({}).populate('child').orFail().then((doc: Parent) => {
  // `doc` doesn't have type information that `child` is populated
  useChildDoc(doc.child);
});

// You can use a function signature to make type checking more strict.
function useChildDoc(child: Child): void {
  console.log(child.name.trim());
}
```

This was lifted from the docs. You can check it [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/typescript/populate.html)

Comment: This works if you use `populate(...).then` but not if you use await to get the result.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for late but here is the [official way](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/typescript/populate.html) to populate using typescript.

```
ItemModel.findById(id).populate<{user: 
{ _id: ObjectId, name: string; email: string} 
}>("user").then((item: Item) => {
    console.log(item.user.name);
})
```

or

```
interface User { user: {_id: ObjectId, name: string; email: string} }

ItemModel.findById(id).populate<User>("user").then((item: Item) => {
    console.log(item.user.name);
})
```