# Populate a query with mongoose in typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I'm having trouble populating my user model with typescript. I have a property of the user's scheme which is the reference to his profile. To implement mongoose with typescript I had to define a tpo / interface in addition to the schema. My problem is that I do not know what type I have to assign to the profile property. Because if I run the query without populating it, it will be an "ObjectId", but if I populate it will contain the whole profile document.

```
export type UserModel = mongoose.Document & {
  name: string;
  username: string; 
  email: string;
  password: string; 
  profile: Schema.Types.ObjectId; // If I leave this property with this type, in case I populate a typescript query it would give me an error. 
};


export const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },

  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  profile: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Profile"
  }
});

export default model<UserModel>("User", UserSchema);
```

Comment: What actually is the question? How to see the "populated" properties in code assistance in later code? Note that "typescript" is not "run-time checking". So this really is not about the "model" definition but more about the code which is attempting to access the structure. See [How to define model in combination with using mongoose populate?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47923466/2313887) if that is what you are really getting at.

Comment: @Neil Lunn Thank you very much, it was just what I was looking for. Now I think I need to eliminate the question so as not to leave a useless duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My problem is that I do not know what type I have to assign to the
>   profile property.

You are going to need to define 2 types/interfaces.

```
export default model<UserModel>("User", UserSchema);
```

This export will have to use a different interface in which you have the populated "Profile" document.

For the schema itself you can leave it as an objectID type.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the populate pointing to the model, this should do the trick

```
 User.find({}).populate([{"path":"profile", "model":"Profile" }])
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Rodrigo Baute, however it does not work for me . Vscode offers me very few methods (which I believe are of ObjectId)